# javascript global variable UNSET

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

For my project i need a editable text ,so i decided to use some plugins but i am also new to jQuery and decided to create my own editable label [inline edit] .

Here is my code :

When user clicks an element with class `editable`

```
$(".editable").live("click",function(){

//alert($(this).text());
//CurrentOBJhtml = $(this).text();
if (typeof CurrentOBJhtml == 'undefined' || CurrentOBJhtml =="" )
{
    CurrentOBJhtml = $(this).text();
}


nextHtml = "<input style='border:1px solid red;' type='text' class='hoverable' value='"+CurrentOBJhtml+"'  />";
var c = nextHtml;
$(this).html(c);
$(this).children().focus();//$(this).focus();

return false;


});
```

When user leaves the `hoverable`

```
$(".hoverable").live("focusout",function(){

var Hovertext = $.trim($(this).val());
if (Hovertext == null || Hovertext=="")
{
$(this).parent().text(CurrentOBJhtml);

}
else
{
$(this).parent().text(Hovertext);
}
return false;

});
```

The Problem is when i start edit first element it works well ,but if there is two element with class `editable` the second one also getting the value of first one ?

Please check the following example :

```
<label class='editable'>userMania1</label>
<label class='editable'>userDirection1</label>
```

i can edit the first label ,but when i click the second one i am getting the value of first one so the second one will be `<label class='editable'>userMania1</label>` which is incorrect.

Please note that i am little bit new to this technology and trying to learn with my current project,how can i solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, `CurrentOBJhtml` is global. You should create a variable local to your plugin function (if you have created a proper jQuery plugin, which might not be the case given the code you've posted). Alternatively you can use `.data()`: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @FelixKling No i dont know how to create a jQuery plugin,is there anyway to solve this ? thank you .

Comment: Sorry, somehow I read that you wanted to create your own plugin ;) If you want to, have a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring. Otherwise, as I already said, use `.data()` to store the value per element instead of a global variable.

Comment: Tidy up your sample code, please...

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com Hai,i am little bit new to this and doing it with the syntax experience from c#..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using global variables makes it difficult to reuse part of your code. In jQuery, you can use [`.data()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to associate arbitrary data with a DOM element.

Here is a cleaned up version of your code:

```
(function() {
    var $input = $('<input style="border:1px solid red;" type="text" />');
    $input.focusout(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        var value = $.trim($(this).val()) || $(this).parent().data('orig_text');
        $(this).parent().text(value);
    });


    $(".editable").live("click",function(event){
        if (event.target === this) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            var text = $(this).text();

            $(this)
             .data('orig_text', text)
             .empty()
             .append($input.clone(true).val(text))
             .children('input').focus();
        }
    });

}());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3BwH/1/)

Also note, since jQuery 1.7, you should use [`.on()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.live()` and bind the event handlers directly to the elements if they already exist.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ,but i need the `focusout` event back which is little bit better,also when i use this i am getting a blank text area ,i need the current value on that text area..

Comment: Don't know why I had `click` first, but of course you can use whatever you want, you just have to adjust the code ;) Fixed it anyways.

Comment: Now when i click the element it getting blank...no input[type='text'] area coming ..

Answer (score 1):

thats due to the following line

```
nextHtml = "<input style='border:1px solid red;' type='text' class='hoverable' value='"+CurrentOBJhtml+"'  />";
```

You are assigning the value to CurrentOBJhtml which is set while editing the first one the correct way to do it is:

```
nextHtml = "<input style='border:1px solid red;' type='text' class='hoverable' value='"+$(this).text();+"'  />";
```

Or you can set CurrentOBJhtml to null at the end of the onfocusout function

Answer (score 0):

avoid to use global variables
but if you desided to use them - use carefully

```
$(".hoverable").live("blur",function(){
    var Hovertext = $.trim($(this).val());
    if (Hovertext == null || Hovertext=="")
    {
        $(this).parent().text(CurrentOBJhtml);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parent().text(Hovertext);
    }
    CurrentOBJhtml = "" //<------ NOTE THIS
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solve it :)

I know this is not the exact way to achieve this & it is dirty.

But for me it works well

I added the following to the click function

```
if ($(this).children().html() == null)
 {
    //alert('I am editable');
    CurrentOBJhtml = $(this).text();
 }
```

NOTE : Please  use Felix's solution ,it is very neat and better one.